# Sorting issue for Decimal128 | no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so that Decimal128 conforms to Comparable<? super U>

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I was trying to sort a list according to a field which is Decimal 128 but getting "no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so that Decimal128 conforms to Comparable<? super U> " error.

```
odsALSAccBalHistoryListFinal =
               alsBHSortLevel1
                   .stream()
                   .sorted(
                       Comparator.comparing(OdsALSAccBalHistory::getSrtCdeAccNum)
                           .thenComparing(OdsALSAccBalHistory::getYrMo, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());`
```

Data Type :

[image]

Kindly suggest if there is a workaround for this.

Comment: What is `Decimal128` implements it `Comparable`?

Comment: `Decimal128` is not a class from standard Java so better be more specific in the question. that is, explain which package/framework it comes from (or at least add the corresponding tag, if one exists)

Comment: Decimal128 comes from import org.bson.types.Decimal128;

Comment: What is `alsBHSortLevel1`. Please add code always as text and as a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
Comparator.comparing(OdsALSAccBalHistory::getSrtCdeAccNum)
```

to

```
Comparator.comparing((OdsALSAccBalHistory ods) -> ods.getSrtCdeAccNum().bigDecimalValue​())
```